# Why does list named "right'" remain unchanged?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to know why this code doesn't change my list `right`.

```
height = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,2,1]
right = [None]*9
for i in reversed(range(9,1)):
    if height[i-1]>height[i]:
        right[9-i-1] = 1
    else:
        right[9-i-1] = 0
print(right)
```

Comment: that range will never exit so im not sure how you can even print right

Comment: `reversed(range(9,1))` is iterating over empty list.

Comment: I added a line about how i initialized the list "right",, @AndrejKesely is there a way to do this differently?

Comment: First, you need `range(9,1,-1)`. Second, what is `n`?

Comment: Debug yourself by adding `print(i)` in your for loop. Then read how `range` works.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code issues `range(9,1)`, which is empty.
2. To iterate 1,2,3,4 use `range(1, 5)`
3. To iterate 4,3,2,1 use `reversed(range(1, 5))` or `range(4, 0, -1)`

Comment: You're right, though `range()` doesn't return a list in Python 3.

Comment: Saying, `range(1, 5)` results in an iterable that iterates over 1,2,3,4 is kind of a mouthful though. and adding the `list()` call around it just adds more code that they have to stare at.

Comment: Absolutely, there isn't really a concise, technically correct way to put it. Although, it might be simpler to ignore the data structure and just talk about the contents: `range(9, 1)` is empty, `range(1, 5)` is `1, 2, 3, 4`, `reversed(range(1, 5))` is `4, 3, 2, 1`.